# Export pandas dataframe to a nested dictionary from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Its a similar question to [this here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/export-pandas-to-dictionary-by-combining-multiple-row-values)

But in this case I want something different.
I have the next dataframe example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
           ['A', 123, 1], 
           ['B', 345, 5], 
           ['C', 712, 4],
           ['B', 768, 2], 
           ['B', 768, 3], 
           ['A', 123, 9], 
           ['C', 178, 6], 
           ['C', 178, 5],  
           ['A', 321, 3]], 
           columns=['maingroup', 'subgroup', 'selectedCol'])
```

And I want to extract a nested dictionary, where the main keys correspond to the unique names in `'maingroup'`, and the subkeys correspond to unique names of `'subgroup'` and the values store arrays of values from `'selectedCol'` with common `'maingroup'` and `'subgroup'` keys, like so:

```
{
 'A': {'123':[1, 9], '321':[3]},
 'B': {'345':[5], '768':[2, 3]},
 'C': {'712':[4], '178':[6, 5]}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dict comprehension with nested groupby:

```
d = {k: f.groupby('subgroup')['selectedCol'].apply(list).to_dict()
     for k, f in df.groupby('maingroup')}
```

[out]

```
{'A': {123: [1, 9], 321: [3]},
 'B': {345: [5], 768: [2, 3]},
 'C': {178: [6, 5], 712: [4]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `MultiIndex Series` and then in dictionary comprehension nested `dict`s:

```
s = df.groupby(['maingroup','subgroup'], sort=False)['selectedCol'].apply(list)
d = {l: s.xs(l).to_dict() for l in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'A': {123: [1, 9], 321: [3]}, 
 'B': {345: [5], 768: [2, 3]}, 
 'C': {712: [4], 178: [6, 5]}}
```

Comment: this also works, but I will accept the previous answer because it's simpler and more transparent. Thank you!

Comment: not much in it from my test... only < 1ms difference with 100000 rows

Comment: Just 3 - concatted the sample df 10,000 times

Comment: I have a 2000 rows dataframe and the difference in time is tenths of miliseconds... precisely 0.4 ms

Comment: @acb - what is number of unique groups? `print (df['maingroup'].nunique())` ?

Comment: It's three as well.

Comment: I see, in any case, as I said, I accept the other answer because to me it is more transparent, although I agree, for a higher number of unique groups yours might be faster.

Comment: @acb - It is no problem with accepting, only I was happy is possible test in real data, but because real data with small huge groups I will wait for another data ;)